# Cant install, stuck in logo . How can I instal elementary?

Tags: system-installation

I create with Rufus iso in a pendrive.
I restart and boot from pendrive, appears the logo, and freeze there 30 minutes..

whats the problem?

Comment: Verify the integrity of your download. If you want a nice and easy way to do this, download it again but this time use the magnet link (it literally looks like a magnet) to the right of the download link. This will require a torrent client, but it will also automatically verify the integrity of the downloaded .ISO file. Let's start with that.

Comment: I just dowload from torrent, and the same. at the third blink of the logo, it stucks....

Comment: Hmm... That's rather unusual. It'd give an error if you were using 32 bit hardware. During the boot process, there's the chance to add some advanced kernel parameters. I am not at the right computer, but I think it's F6. Press the F6 button and try turning ACPI off and using 'nomodeset'. You do it with the keyboard, pressing enter (as memory serves) to confirm them.